# How does Adobe CC launch itself?

Tags: macos, adobe-creative-cloud

Adobe Creative Cloud is not listed here

[image]

... but it opens when I login. How?

Comment: Is it registered with `launchd` at `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Comment: @pun This is the answer!

Comment: Did you just delete the plist or unload it ? Post it as an answer for others to know

Comment: I have not done anything to attempt to disable the updater from launching. I am just curious how it was loading. I know it is active because it CONSTANTLY uses my internet connection even when I do not have Adobe apps "open".

Comment: You want to stop Adobe CC or the updater ? Checked [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1024666)